# Closing a connection when using two different connections and the same model files

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, electron, sequelize.js

I'm having a little difficulty with my sequelize setup and looking for some guidance/help.

The scenario I'm working with as follows:

1. Electronjs application that has two sequelize connections: sqlite and mssql.
2. The sqlite connection is built on booting of the application - works fine.
3. The MSSQL is connected when the user requests that the connection is made - this too seems to be working fine.
4. The user has the ability to 'close' the MSSQL connection, so the application needs to fall back to the sqlite connection. This is where the issue seems to be...

In short the sqlite is the 'offline' working area, but when the user connects to the live system, the data needs to be migrated, but becomes the working connection for the application, such that they can continue to edit things 'online'. However, the user  may decide to 'disconnect' from the live server and therefore the application needs to revert to the sqlite database.

The live servers are 'configurable' so there may be more than one 'live' connection to create, hence I can't create it on boot and then have it there for evermore, the user may switch between two different live servers.

However, as both the live and offline databases are the copies of each other, I have one set of Model definitions and want to basically 'swap out' the sequelize connection when one connects/disconnects. So this is what I have at the moment:

```js
'use strict';

const {
    app,
} = require('electron');
const logger = require('electron-log');

const path = require('path');
const {
    Sequelize, Op,
} = require('sequelize');

const userData = app.getPath('userData');
const dbFile = path.resolve(userData, 'library_v2.sqlite');
logger.debug(dbFile);

import {
    SequelizeStorage, Umzug, 
} from 'umzug';

const db = {
};

// Define the 'default' sqlite connection:
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    retry: {
        max: 50,
    },
    storage: dbFile,
    logging: msg => logger.debug(msg),
});

// Init the mssql connection:
let mssqlConnection = null;

// This is my connect function which works:
export const connect = (config, data) => {
    mssqlConnection = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
        dialect: 'mssql',
        retry: {
            max: 5,
        },
        host: config.host,
        port: config.port,
        logging: msg => logger.debug(msg),
    });

    Object.values(db.sequelize.models)
        .forEach(model => {
            // Swap out the sequelize connection:
            model.sequelize = mssqlConnection;
        });

    ...

    db.sequelize = mssqlConnection;
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
    db.Op = Op;

    ...

    // Run the migration and seeds:
    const check = initialiseDatabase(mssqlConnection);
    return check.then(() => {
        return true;
    });
};

// This is my disconnect function which doesn't work... maybe...
export const disconnect = async () => {
    console.log('Disconnecting');
    await mssqlConnection.close();
    ...
    PT = null;
    mssqlConnection = null;

    // Reset the sequelize to the sqlite:
    Object.values(db.sequelize.models)
        .forEach(model => {
            model.sequelize = sequelize;
        });

    db.sequelize = sequelize;
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
    db.Op = Op;

    ...

    return true;
};
...

// Staging models:
db.Modules = require('./modules')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
db.Sequences = require('./sequences')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
...

Object.keys(db)
    .forEach(async (modelName) => {
        if (db[modelName].associate) {

            db[modelName].associate(db);
        }
    });
...

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.Op = Op;

...

export default db;
```

The connection seems to work fine and I can use the new connection for working with the data, but when I try and disconnect, as far as I can tell everything is 'reset' to work with the original sqlite database, but an error is thrown:

```bash
Error: ConnectionManager.getConnection was called after the connection manager was closed!
    at ConnectionManager.getConnection ([...]/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:74:13)
    at [...]/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:305:111
    at [...]/node_modules/retry-as-promised/dist/index.js:59:25
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at retryAsPromised ([...]/node_modules/retry-as-promised/dist/index.js:48:12)
    at Timeout._onTimeout ([...]/node_modules/retry-as-promised/dist/index.js:94:21)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
```

From my debugging, I'm pretty sure that everything is completing and completing but as soon as I try and 'get' the data from the sqlite database it's throwing this error. So there seems like there's either a stray promise that's not completing until after the disconnect.

I've checked the model that I'm 'getting' the new data from after disconnect and it shows the correct sequelize connection - dialect and file for the db - so I'm fairly sure it has disconnected. However, the get is failing and then the app stops loading anything from the database - every get for all models are reporting the same error. The only solution is to kill the app and restart it.

Does anyone have any ideas of what I might be missing with this?

Note: I have trimmed the code down a little to remove most of the models, migrations and seeders using umzug, and some sequelize-revision tracking (these all work so don't think they're of need), but there are no errors with compilation. If you think there may be something else at play, happy to provide more if you think it's needed.

Comment: Thanks @ThomA - my apologies - I wasn't trying to tag, just note is sequelize.

Comment: We can tell it's sequelize from the tags though; that's the point of them. As mentioned in [ask]: *"**Don't include tags in the title**. The system will automatically prepend the most important tag to your title for search-engine optimization purposes. You don't need to (and shouldn't) do it manually. If you want to include the name of the language/library/framework/tool, do it in regular English, not as a bracketed tag."*

Answer (score 0):

So after a number of trial and errors, I stumbled across the 'solution' which boils down to the 'order'.

In order to get this to work, the disconnect function needed to be:

```js
// This is my disconnect function which doesn't work... maybe...
export const disconnect = async () => {
    // Apparently this needs to be before the .forEach:
    db.sequelize = sequelize;
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
    db.Op = Op;

    // Reset the sequelize to the sqlite:
    Object.values(db.sequelize.models)
        .forEach(model => {
            model.sequelize = sequelize;
        });

    console.log('Disconnecting');
    await mssqlConnection.close();
    ...
    PT = null;
    mssqlConnection = null;

    ...

    return true;
};
```

I'm not entirely sure why this was the working answer - I'm guessing that the models need to be reassigned to the sqlite sequelize, before the old connection is disconnected. Otherwise, it looks like they get stuck in a sort of limbo where the Models aren't sure what the connection really is and try to use the disconnected mssql connection.